# Result consisted of more than one row during insert

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I am having a problem with a stored procedure in `MySQL 5.5.41`. The problem is that during the procedure execution error is thrown - `Error code: 1172, SQLState: 42000, Message: Result consisted of more than one row`. The strange thing is that it is thrown while executing statement:

```
    INSERT INTO TB__X
           (FK__A, FK__B, FK__C, FK__D, E, F, G, H, I, J, L)
        VALUES 
           (9106, 4927, NULL, 3, 4.9990234375, 20, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1);
```

The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `TB__X` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`FK__A` int(11) NOT NULL,
`FK__B` int(11) NOT NULL,
`FK__C` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`FK__D` int(11) NOT NULL,
`E` double NOT NULL,
`F` int(11) NOT NULL,
`G` double NOT NULL,
`H` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`I` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`J` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`K` TEXT,
`L` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `IX_U_1` (`FK__B`,`FK__C`,`D`),
KEY `I__2` (`FK__A`),
KEY `I__3` (`FK__C`),
KEY `I__4` (`F`),
KEY `I__5` (`FK__D`),
CONSTRAINT `FK__1` FOREIGN KEY (`FK__B`) REFERENCES `TB__B` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK__2` FOREIGN KEY (`F`) REFERENCES `TB__F` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK__3` FOREIGN KEY (`FK__C`) REFERENCES `TB__C` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK__4` FOREIGN KEY (`FK__D`) REFERENCES `TB__D` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK__5` FOREIGN KEY (`FK__A`) REFERENCES `TB__A` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13575 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Does anyone know what this error means on `insert` statement?

Comment: Is the procedure is doing some select and then insert ? If yes then the select values must use cursor and insert should happen in loop.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be the `INSERT` statement (see [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8c47/1)), at least not as a single statement. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @abhikchakraborty The procedure is doing SELECT INTO variable statements, but using MAX/MIN, LIMIT 1 or equality conditions on unique indexes

Comment: @wchiquito That's what I thought... But I have run the queries, one by one, from the procedure, and the error is raised during execution of this INSERT. This is the exact query that is causing issues. What more details could I provide?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2) or provide the `SELECT INTO` with some test data?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have find out the cause of the issue. It turned out that there was a `TRIGGER AFTER INSERT` on the table that I was inserting data, and inside the trigger was a `SELECT INTO` statement that was returning more than one row.